# Getting InnoSetup to use uninstalled app's previous directory

Tags: inno-setup

A have an app that must be uninstalled before it can be upgraded (not something I can change).

Of course, the default directory for the new install should be where the previous version was installed. But since the app has been uninstalled UsePreviousAppDir doesn't work.

What would be the best way to get an uninstalled app's directory? Is there anywhere it is stored? How would a new registry entry be managed for this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to find the previous location of the app after it has been uninstalled, short of asking the user to remember this and re-enter it.

However, a simple solution to this issue is to trigger the uninstall from within the upgrader itself -- `UsePreviousAppDir` takes effect when the wizard first opens, so it's safe to discover the previous app dir and uninstall at any point after that.  The most recommended time to do it is from the [`PrepareToInstall` handler](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptevents.htm#PrepareToInstall).

Bear in mind that it still could be possible that you won't be able to find the prior path, either because the user manually uninstalled before running the upgrader or because the install failed, crashed, or was cancelled after it successfully uninstalled the prior version.  So you'll need a backup (such as asking the user, or assuming some reasonable default) anyway.

Be very sure that you really do need to uninstall beforehand, though -- while there are a few cases where it is required (such as when the prior version was not installed with Inno -- in which case `UsePreviousAppDir` isn't going to help you either), most of the time you should just install over the top, using flags and [`[InstallDelete]` entries](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_installdeletesection.htm) to skip or remove old files as needed.